# Angular retrieve data from API

Tags: angular, api, components

I'm working on retrieving data from different API's and I am facing some issues.

The first part is working well, the code is below :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.http.get('http://.../api/getData?table=getdata&filter=remediation_status:1')
    .subscribe( data => { this.incidents = data, console.log(data);})
}
```

For the second step, I try to retrieve data from another API URL and in the same component using values retrieved during the first step but there are seen as "undefined".

```
For example `console.log(this.incidents); ` returns "undefined" while it's defined just above.
```

Is it possible to do retrieve data from an API and used it in the same component (in the ngOnInit():) or not ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Please identify the issue and explain it correctly, this isn't clear at all. You can also provide a [mcve].

Comment: @trichetriche Yes, it wasn't clear, I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the second code is after the first one, so, let me explain a little bit:
Your code will be read in this way:

- Your HTTP call will be started, but it doesn't stop the code flow
- The code that is after that HTTP call will run, even if the HTTP is not done
- The variable that you set in the HTTP call will be as undefined because the HTTP call has not finished
- In some part your variable will have data because the HTTP call will be done, but not in the moment that you want

So, there are 2 ways to handle this:

- You could set the second code that you have into a function, and call that function from the subscribe method of your HTTP Request, in that way, you will have the data that you need to consume
- You could use async & await to wait 'till your HTTP Request is done, and continue executing the code, it means it will read your HTTP call, but it will not continue executing your code 'till that's done, you coul read more about this [here](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-async-await-feature-in-angular-587dd56fdc77) and [here](https://labs.encoded.io/2016/12/08/asyncawait-with-angular/)